# How can I return a text fragment from an XPath function?

Tags: python, lxml

Supposing I have an XPath function I'm calling from an XSL transform using `lxml` (with `libxml` and `libxslt`), eg:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="result" select="myns:my-func(./*)" />
  ...
</xsl:template>
```

From this function, I'd like to return an XML fragment that consists the following:

```
some sample <em>text</em>
```

The python function `my_func` is set-up correctly using `lxml` to be available via the XSL stylesheet, and used `lxml.html.fragments_fromstring` to obtain the results which are in the format:

`['some sample ', <Element em at 0x106c203b0>]`

How can I return this list so it can be used later in the XSL transform from the variable as though it were collected from an XPath expression directly in the XSL context? It seems that whenever I pass a list of strings back to the XSL processor `lxml` throws an exception.

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to know how you can access a Python function from XML? Or do you already have the Python linked to your XSLT processor and it delivers different results from what you need? Which results are these, and how do you expect tehm? Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: @unpluggd What part of my answer did not work for you? Would it help if I provided something like a pastebin link with a full working example?

Comment: @JamesHolderness If you could provide a working example that would be wonderful! I've personally tried your approach and it didn't work for me, which led me to try creating "smart string" objects and other solutions that didn't work. I've awarded you the bounty anyway, and will accept your answer with a working example. Thanks!

Comment: @unpluggd I've added a pastebin link to my answer. Also, in case it makes any difference, I'm testing on Python 2.6 and lxml 3.2.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing is to define your function. It needs to return the node-set as a list of items. The items may include Elements (also comments and processing instructions), strings and tuples.

A hardcoded example might look like this:

```
from lxml import etree

def myFunc(context, parm):
  em = etree.Element('em')
  em.text = 'text'
  return ['some sample ', em]
```

Note that the *parm* parameter isn't necessary in this case, but I've included it here to match your example code which is passing a parameter in the call to *myns:my-func*.

And if you wanted to use the *fragments_fromstring* to construct your node-set, rather than building it manually, the function definition becomes even simpler.

```
def myFunc(context, parm):           
  import lxml.html
  return lxml.html.fragments_fromstring('some sample <em>text</em>')
```

Next you need to setup the namespace and register the function name.

```
myns = etree.FunctionNamespace('http://example.org/myNamespace')
myns['my-func'] = myFunc
```

And finally you can use it from within an XSLT stylesheet like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:myns="http://example.org/myNamespace">
  <xsl:template match="/">                                   
    <xsl:variable name="result" select="myns:my-func(./*)" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$result">
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>         
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the namespace URL used in the stylesheet must match the one registered in the *FunctionNamespace*.

Now assuming you've loaded this stylesheet into a string called *xslt*, an example transform might look like this:

```
root = etree.XML('<root></root>')
doc = etree.ElementTree(root)
transform = etree.XSLT(etree.XML(xslt))
res = transform(doc)
```

For a full working example, see this [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/Fdxw6BzT).

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.3 and lxml 3.2.1, ran the pastebin code, and got an error: `XSLTApplyError: Failed to evaluate the expression of variable 'result'.`

Comment: @unpluggd I've just done a clean install of python 2.7.3 from [here](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.3/) (the Windows x86 MSI Installer) and lxml 3.2.1 from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.2.1) (the Windows 32bit installer - lxml-3.2.1.win32-py2.7.exe), and my example still works fine for me. Could it be an OS issue? Are you on Linux? Either way, it might be worth trying to reinstall python and lxml.

Comment: @unpluggd It just occurred to me it might also be a problem with the version of libxml or libxslt that you are using if you have installed those separately.

Comment: @unpluggd Looking at the [installation requirements](http://lxml.de/installation.html#requirements) they are very picky about which versions of libxml and libxslt you need. It is recommended you use libxml2 2.7.8 or later and libxslt 1.1.26 or later.